# How to make a shortcut to access Windows advanced security settings on files?

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, shortcuts

I wonder if there is a way to make a shortcut to reach advanced security tab. Every time I want to set security permissions on files I have to click 4 times just to get the advanced security tab, this is very repetitive and annoying task what I have to do when setting permissions on big number of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easily, you just need to make some changes to the registry.

Open Registry Editor. Go to the following Registry key:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell

Create a new subkey called 'Windows.RibbonPermissionsDialog'

In the 'Windows.RibbonPermissionsDialog' subkey create a new string value named 'ExplorerCommandHandler'

Set its value data to {E2765AC3-564C-40F9-AC12-CD393FBAAB0F}

Create one more string value named 'CommandStateSync' and leave its value data empty (Default)

Create a new string value named 'Position' and set its value data to 'Bottom'

And the last value you need to create is a new string value named 'Icon'. Set its value data to the following string: ntshrui.dll,-122

Now, you need to perform exactly the same steps at the following Registry keys:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Windows.RibbonPermissionsDialog
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Windows.RibbonPermissionsDialog
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Windows.RibbonPermissionsDialog
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.AssocFile.URL\shell\Windows.RibbonPermissionsDialog

Exit and restart. Now the 'Advanced Security Settings' will be available in the context menu when you right-click on a file.

Source - https://winaero.com/how-to-add-advanced-security-to-context-menu-in-windows-10/

Comment: You should try to at least précis the solution, otherwise if the link disappears so does the validity of this answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Done. I thought I had reached the character limit but there was enough room after all.

Comment: Cool thanks. I've never hit the char limit & some of my posts are like novellas;) Perhaps it's different if you're relatively new, but it's not something I was aware of. Welcome to Super User. Enjoy your stay :))